Storing data in JSON format in MySql vs storing in each column
My team storing the JSON data in JSON format under column, usually the each value in JSON is stored under respective column? Why? Is there any advantage to store like that? Someone explain me the Pros and Cons for this
Answer from the developers

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are advantages (and disadvantages) of using JSON (in this case, the MySQL json data type) in database data. JSON allows data de-normalization of the otherwise relational and normalized data. Other features include storing unstructured data, and composite data like arrays and objects. JSON structures also allow quick prototyping of applications. This is generally a broad topic, and I think a quick search on the internet can get you more information.

Ask your team not stackoverflow, they decided to do it like this.

When the only operations with this JSON are store, replace with new value, retrieve complete JSON and delete then JSON column may be used. If there are more operations (searching, sorting and so on) then parsing and storing in separate columns is more reasonable.
